# ng-change not getting called on checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have a select dropdown. Upon selecting each value in dropdown, checkboxes are created using ng-repeat. All the values in the dropdown are supposed to be selected and corresponding checkboxes are stored in an array when a checkbox is checked using `ng-change` on the checkbox.

When I change back to a previous dropdown value, I am checking if the checkboxes are already there in the array used to store checked values and then check them using `ng-check` on load.

But when I uncheck the loaded checkboxes, SOMETIMES the ng-change is not called. I don't understand why.

**When I check and uncheck it again, then it works.**

Storing and removing checked values on checkbox change:

```
    $scope.checkChanged = function(isChecked, flat){
        //debugger;
        console.log("check change");
        if(isChecked != -1){
            let tempArray = [];
            for(let i=0; i<$scope.userEventData.selectedFlats.length; i++){
                tempArray.push($scope.userEventData.selectedFlats[i].flat_id);
            }
            if(!tempArray.includes(flat.flat_id)){
                $scope.userEventData.selectedFlats.push(flat);
                console.log("pushed new", flat.flat_no);
            }
        }else{
            $scope.userEventData.selectedFlats = $scope.userEventData.selectedFlats.filter(function(f){
                console.log(f, flat.flat_id);
                return f.flat_id != flat.flat_id
            });
            console.log("removed", flat.flat_no);
        }
        console.log($scope.userEventData.selectedFlats, "pushed check");
}
```

`$scope.flatsArray` is the array used to generate checkboxes using `ng-repeat`.
Set checkbox to checked or unchecked based on array storing checked values`($scope.userEventData.selectedFlats)`:

```
.then(function successCallback(response){ 
        $scope.flatsArray = response.data.body.Data;

        for(let d=0; d< $scope.flatsArray.length; d++){

            $scope.flatsArray[d].isChecked = false;

        }

        if($scope.userEventData.selectedFlats.length){
            let tempSelectedFlat = [];
            for(let j=0; j<$scope.userEventData.selectedFlats.length; j++){
                tempSelectedFlat.push($scope.userEventData.selectedFlats[j].flat_id);
            }
            console.log(tempSelectedFlat,"tempSelectedFlat");

            /** If present in selectedFlats set ng-checked to true **/
            for(let d=0; d< $scope.flatsArray.length; d++){
                console.log(d, "d");
                console.log($scope.flatsArray[d].flat_id, "$scope.flatsArray[d].flat_id");
                console.log(tempSelectedFlat.includes($scope.flatsArray[d].flat_id));
                if(tempSelectedFlat.includes($scope.flatsArray[d].flat_id)){
                    $scope.flatsArray[d].isChecked = true;
                }else{
                    $scope.flatsArray[d].isChecked = false;
                }

            }
        }else{
            for(let d=0; d< $scope.flatsArray.length; d++){

                $scope.flatsArray[d].isChecked = false;

            }
        }
```

The html:

```
    <div class="ScrollStyle">
   <div ng-repeat="flat in flatsArray" class="row" style="width:90%;">
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input class="" name="{{flat.flat_no}}" 
            type="checkbox" ng-true-value="{{flat.flat_id}}" 
            ng-false-value="'-1'" 
            ng-checked="flat.isChecked"
            ng-change="checkChanged(sFlats[$index], flat)" ng-model="sFlats[$index]" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10"><label for="{{flat.flat_no}}">{{flat.flat_no}}</label></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

`$scope.flatsArray`:

```
   0: {flat_id: "9", flat_no: "1", isChecked: false, $$hashKey: "object:62"}
1
:
{flat_id: "10", flat_no: "2", isChecked: false, $$hashKey: "object:63"}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample json of `flatsArray` ?

Comment: @Kailas posted it

Comment: Since it is an input, what happens if you change it to: `ng-model="flat.isChecked"` instead of using *ng-checked*.  Also, it might be beneficial to you to have some console.log statements in order to determine what is and is not being processed in your controller.  This might put you closer to your desired end-state?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676631/angularjs-checkbox-and-ng-change . NGCHECKED will modify the checked attribute, but if you want 2-way binding, I believe the ng-model is the way to go.  I almost exclusively use *ng-model* for forms

Comment: @Fallenreaper can you please write it as an answer with a little code?

Comment: Did it work for you, or..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition of ng-checked and ng-model, you are not suppose to use them both.  Ideally you should just use ng-model. `ng-model="flat.isChecked"` . If you add some log statements you will know a bit more as to what is being fired or not.

Here is some information you may enjoy: [Angularjs: checkbox and ng-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676631/angularjs-checkbox-and-ng-change)

ng-checked will modify the checked attribute, but if you want binding, ng-model will be the best.  I almost exclusively use *ng-model* in all of my forms.

The Logs will give you more insight to know what is actually being fired.  If something is not being fired, then it means the event is not wired correctly.